# Error when trying to export Community template

Tags: community, template

I am receiving the following error when trying to export a Community template.  We don't have over 175 pages and theme layouts in our Community.
"We ran into a few problems.  We can't validate the page you're exporting. Your template can have up to 175 pages and theme layouts.  Remove pages or theme layouts  to keep the total within the limit.

[image]